# Problems with scrollbar in IE9, position: fixed, overflow: auto

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've encountered a strange issue with the vertical scroll bar on IE9 when using a div with a fixed position and overflow: auto set on the div.

See the case here using IE9 and shrink the window height down to a small size.

http://bytiger.com/add/ie9_div_test.html

I can confirm that this doesn't occur on IE8.

Does anyone know a reasonable hack around this?  I've tried setting the width to the window width, but it seems that it purposesfully subtracts a scrollbar width from the size of the div.  I would like to see if there is a solution that doesn't have to calculate this constant or hardcode it and adding this back to the calculated width.

Cheers!

EDIT: Jsfiddle doesn't seem to exhibit the problem... so that can be a big hint as to what might be going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvAKW/

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but in IE9 you must need units whereas possible. If unit is omitted, IE9 ignores the rule. You have a lot of unitless rules in your css (including main/common.css).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems like IE9 doesn't handle the [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property correctly - changing it from "border-box" to "content-box" or leaving it blank will fix your problem.

Comment: IE9 seems like the only one that doesn't like box-sizing with absolutely positioned elements in fixed positioned elements. or some combination of those

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an acceptable solution. Setting box-sizing to content-box defies the purpose, because then you can't use width:100% and expect it to size the element accordingly, taking padding into account.

Comment: Well, I think it's acceptable. If you understand how `content-box` works then you can just set the width accordingly - 100% minus any padding you've placed on it - assuming you use a separate stylesheet for old IE. Also, ensure that you set `box-sizing: border-box` on all children, as `content-box` will be inherited.